# Calling the method directly works, but calling it with a strategy pattern does not

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When Sequelize init instance i have 'getBlocks' and 'getSkills' methods, so i need to adopt an strategy pattern to know what method i have to call

```js
  const resourceTypes = instance => ({
    Block: instance.getBlocks,
    Skill: instance.getSkills
  });

  return resourceTypes(this)[this.dataValues.type]();
```

But that call returns to me this throw

```
TypeError: instance.get is not a function
    at BelongsToMany.get (/home/fparol4/Desktop/work/repositories/assessment-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:434:48)
    at Object.obj.<computed> [as Block] (/home/fparol4/Desktop/work/repositories/assessment-api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/helpers.js:64:39)
    at Question.findResource (/home/fparol4/Desktop/work/repositories/assessment-api/src/api/v1/models/Question.js:29:51)
    at QuestionService.findByPk (/home/fparol4/Desktop/work/repositories/assessment-api/src/api/v1/services/QuestionService.js:183:35)
    at async show (/home/fparol4/Desktop/work/repositories/assessment-api/src/api/v1/controllers/QuestionController.js:100:22)
```

Calling the method directly, for example:

> return this.getBlocks()

No throw is throwed